# Como repito una funcion entre cada linea?

Tags: python, funciones

estoy aprendiendo Python y necesitaría saber si existe alguna forma de repetir una función entre lineas sin tener que llamarla cada vez que quiera usarla.

Mi código esta así

```py
def tiempo():
    i=0

    import time

    while i<5:
        i=i+1        
        # tiempo en segundos
        time.sleep(0.4)

def prepararCafe():
    print("Observo, localizo e identifico el lugar donde se guarda el café")
    tiempo()
    print("Localizo el lugar donde se guarda el café")
    tiempo()
    print("Me dirijo hacia el lugar donde se guarda el café")
    tiempo()
    print("Procedo a identificar el frasco de café")
    tiempo()
    print("Una vez identificado el frasco, procedo a tomar el frasco de café con mi mano derecha")
    tiempo()
    print("Me pongo en modo espera")
    tiempo()
    print("En modo espera, procedo a identificar inmuebles de tipo mesa")
    tiempo()
    print("Logro identificar una mesa")
    tiempo()
    print("Procedo a dirigirme hacia la respectiva mesa")
    tiempo()
    print("Una vez delante de la mesa, procedo a dejar el frasco de café sobre la mesa")
    tiempo()
    print("Me pongo en modo espera")
    tiempo()
    print("En modo espera, procedo a observar, localizar e identificar el lugar donde se guardan las tazas")
    tiempo()
    print("Localizo el lugar donde se guardan las tazas")
    tiempo()
    print("Una vez localizado el lugar donde se guardan las tazas, procedo a dirigirme hacia ese lugar")
    tiempo()
    print("Procedo a identificar objetos de tipo taza")
    tiempo()
    print("Una vez identificada la taza, procedo a tomar la taza con mi mano derecha")
    tiempo()
    print("Procedo a dirigirme hacia la mesa previamente localizada")
    tiempo()
    print("Una vez delante de la mesa, procedo a dejar la taza sobre la mesa")
    tiempo()
    print("xD")

prepararCafe()
```

Lo que necesito es una forma de llamar a la función tiempo() entre cada linea, sin tener que llamarla entre cada linea

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: Si no me equivoco, parece que intentas algún proceso concurrente (*modelo actor* tal vez?). El bucle de la función `tiempo` no tiene sentido a no ser que lo que prentendas sea agrupar 5 tareas, cada una con sus `0.4` segundos de espera. No obstante, la respuesta a tu pregunta ya la tienes. Si quieres algo más, haz otra pregunta y complétala con la información que sea necesaria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Así como lo describes no se me ocurre, pero puedes definir una función, que dado un string como parámetro, haga un `print` y luego llame a `tiempo()`. Algo así:

```
def printYTiempo(text):
    print(text)
    tiempo()
```

El programa te quedaría así

```
def tiempo():
    i=0

    import time

    while i<5:
        i=i+1        
        # tiempo en segundos
        time.sleep(0.4)

def printYTiempo(text):
    print(text)
    tiempo()

def prepararCafe():
    printYTiempo("Observo, localizo e identifico el lugar donde se guarda el café")
    printYTiempo("Localizo el lugar donde se guarda el café")
    printYTiempo("Me dirijo hacia el lugar donde se guarda el café")
    printYTiempo("Procedo a identificar el frasco de café")
    printYTiempo("Una vez identificado el frasco, procedo a tomar el frasco de café con mi mano derecha")
    printYTiempo("Me pongo en modo espera")
    printYTiempo("En modo espera, procedo a identificar inmuebles de tipo mesa")
    printYTiempo("Logro identificar una mesa")
    printYTiempo("Procedo a dirigirme hacia la respectiva mesa")
    printYTiempo("Una vez delante de la mesa, procedo a dejar el frasco de café sobre la mesa")
    printYTiempo("Me pongo en modo espera")
    printYTiempo("En modo espera, procedo a observar, localizar e identificar el lugar donde se guardan las tazas")
    printYTiempo("Localizo el lugar donde se guardan las tazas")
    printYTiempo("Una vez localizado el lugar donde se guardan las tazas, procedo a dirigirme hacia ese lugar")
    printYTiempo("Procedo a identificar objetos de tipo taza")
    printYTiempo("Una vez identificada la taza, procedo a tomar la taza con mi mano derecha")
    printYTiempo("Procedo a dirigirme hacia la mesa previamente localizada")
    printYTiempo("Una vez delante de la mesa, procedo a dejar la taza sobre la mesa")
    print("xD")

prepararCafe()
```

Luego, si siempre son esos pasos, puedes definir una lista con esos pasos y en un bucle llamarlo todo:

```
def tiempo():
    i=0

    import time

    while i<5:
        i=i+1        
        # tiempo en segundos
        time.sleep(0.4)

pasosPrepararCafe = [
    "Localizo el lugar donde se guarda el café",
    "Me dirijo hacia el lugar donde se guarda el café",
    "Procedo a identificar el frasco de café",
    "Una vez identificado el frasco, procedo a tomar el frasco de café con mi mano derecha",
    "Me pongo en modo espera",
    "En modo espera, procedo a identificar inmuebles de tipo mesa",
    "Logro identificar una mesa",
    "Procedo a dirigirme hacia la respectiva mesa",
    "Una vez delante de la mesa, procedo a dejar el frasco de café sobre la mesa",
    "Me pongo en modo espera",
    "En modo espera, procedo a observar, localizar e identificar el lugar donde se guardan las tazas",
    "Localizo el lugar donde se guardan las tazas",
    "Una vez localizado el lugar donde se guardan las tazas, procedo a dirigirme hacia ese lugar",
    "Procedo a identificar objetos de tipo taza",
    "Una vez identificada la taza, procedo a tomar la taza con mi mano derecha",
    "Procedo a dirigirme hacia la mesa previamente localizada",
    "Una vez delante de la mesa, procedo a dejar la taza sobre la mesa"
]

for paso in pasosPrepararCafe:
    print(paso)
    tiempo()
```

Comment: Gracias, me funcionó a la perfección!
Ahora te acepto la respuesta, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Yo haría una lista con todos los `str` que necesitas y después utilizaría un bucle for:

```
eventos = ["Observo, localizo e identifico el lugar donde se guarda el café",
           "Localizo el lugar donde se guarda el café",
           "Me dirijo hacia el lugar donde se guarda el café",
           "Procedo a identificar el frasco de café",
           "Una vez identificado el frasco, procedo a tomar el frasco de café con mi mano derecha",
           "Me pongo en modo espera",
           "En modo espera, procedo a identificar inmuebles de tipo mesa",
           "Logro identificar una mesa",
           ...]

for acción in eventos:
    print(acción)
    tiempo()
```

El tipo `list` es especialmente interesante porque nos permite conservar el orden de las cadenas (o modificarlo si es necesario).

A este proceso, el de eliminar multiplicaciones innecesarias, se le conoce como 'factorizar código' y es especialmente importante en Python ya que nos permite evitar errores. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias, lo voy a tener en cuenta y a poner en practica!